# How to retrieve EMF annotations at runtime

Tags: annotations, emf

I have an EMF model, and I'm trying to add documentation to it in the form on EAnnotations on the EClasses. This documentation needs to be able to be retrieved at runtime for various reports. However, trying to get them through EClass.getEAnnotation returns nothing.

I have the annotations set up like so:

```
Source: http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/GenModel
Details:
 Key: documention
 Value: Stuff I'm trying to access goes here.
```

The "Suppress GenModel Annotations" option in the model's .genmodel is set to true. I did regenerate the code after adding the annotations. The documentation annotations show up in the JavaDoc in the generated code.
Both getEAnnotations() and getEAnnotation("GenModel") return nulls. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Suppress GenModel Annotations to false (since you want to include them, not suppress them).

Use the [EcoreUtil.getDocumentation method](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/EcoreUtil.html#getDocumentation%28org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EModelElement%29) to get the actual information.